# Embedding compressed files into a c++ program

Tags: c++, installation, cross-platform

I want to create a cross-platform installer, in c++. It can be any compression type, eg zip or gzip, embedded inside the program itself like an average installer. I don't want to create many changes on different platforms, linux and windows. How do I embed and extract files to a c++ program, cross-platform?

Comment: Well, just go ahead, you don't need our permission. Or did you intend to ask something?

Comment: @Erik, after getting a question closed because people where asking to many 'off-topic' questions, about 4 times. You begin to start writing much larger, less to the point questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is a poor choice for a cross-platform installer, because there's no such thing as cross-platform machine code.

C++ code can be extremely portable, but it needs to be compiled for each platform, and then you get a distinct output executable for each platform.

If you want to build installers for many platforms from a single source file, you can use C++.  But if you want to build ONE installer that works on many platforms, you'll need to use an interpreted or JIT-compiled language with runtime support available on all your targets.  Of those, the only one likely to already be installed on a majority of computers of each platform is Java.

---

Ok, assuming that you're building many single-platform installers from machine code, this is what is needed:

You need to get the compressed code into the program.  You want to do this in a way that doesn't affect the load time badly, nor cause compilation to take a few months.  So using an initialized global array is a bad idea.

One way is to link your data in as an additional section.  There are tools to help with that, e.g. [Binary to COFF converter](http://www.vortex.masmcode.com/), I've seen an ELF version as well, maybe [this](http://www.taniwha.com/~paul/res/).  But this might still cause the runtime library to try to lead the entire file into memory before execution begins.

Another way is to use platform-specific resource APIs.  This is efficient, but platform specific.

The most straightforward solution is to simply append the compressed archive to your executable, then append eight more bytes with the file offset where the compressed archive begins.  Unpacking is then as simple as opening the executable in read-only mode, `fseek(-8, SEEK_END)`, reading the correct offset, then seeking to the beginning of the compressed data and passing that stream to your decompressor.

---

Of course, now I find [a website listing pretty much the same methods](http://www.strchr.com/creating_self-extracting_executables).

And [here's a program which implements the last option](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/self_extractor.aspx), with additional ability to store multiple files.  I wouldn't recommend doing that, let the compression library take care of storing the file metadata.

Comment: This doesn't help! I am well aware I will have to compile it separately, on every platform. C++ is cross-platform because you write once, compile everywhere.

Comment: @Will03uk: Now I understand you want to make many platform-specific installers from a common codebase.  This should be more helpful, I hope.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am wanting to go with the last option, but are there any tutorials to show exactly what the steps are. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to portably embed data (strings or raw, binary
data) in a C++ program is to convert it into a data table, then compile
that.  For raw data, this would look something like:

```
unsigned char data[] =
{
    //  raw data here.
};
```

It should be fairly trivial to write a small program which reads your
binary data, and writes it out as a C++ table, like the above.  Compile
it, and link it into your program, and there you are.

Comment: How much RAM does your compiler use trying to process a few hundred megabyte array initializer?  You can keep the source code manageable using `#include`, but still, the compile time will be horrendous.

Comment: The compile time isn't so bad---it's some of the simplest code to compile (nothing like templates).  I have had the compiler run out of memory if the data is too large, however.  This solution would probably only work for very small images.

Answer (score 0):

Use zlib.

Have your packing program generate a list of exe's in the program. i,e.

```
unsigned char x86_windows_version[] = { 0xff,...,0xff};
unsigned char arm_linux_version[] = { 0xff,...,0xff};

unsigned char* binary_files[MAX_BINARIES] = {x86_windows_version,arm_linux_version};
```

somewhere in your excitable:

```
enflate(x86_windows_version);
```

And thats about it. Look at the zlib docs for the parameters for enflate() and deflate() and that's about it.

It's a pattern used a lot on embedded platforms (that are not linux) mostly for string _tables and other image binaries. It should work for your needs.

Comment: This is absolutely useless.  Which target do you compile this all-in-one installer for?

Comment: You have to link it against the small binary that it for each platform. These only have to be built once as any changes to the deliverable binaries are build and linked against the small binaries. So one cross-platform build (you include zlib in you build tree) and that's it. simple.

Comment: @PA: But since the installer binary is only good for one platform, why wouldn't you attach just the archive containing the program for that one platform, and not embed other platform archives that would require a different installer anyway?

Comment: @ben: yes, did not think of that. :) But, but then link the deflated data into JAVA. It then works fine. (I know he only wants c++). zlib for the c/c++ installer still a good idea, as it works on any platform with a C8?+ compiler. (done something similar for internationalisation and it has run on WinXX,MacOS,OS21,Linux - without changing the packer/unpacker - `make release` generates them all). No/v.little maintenance.